# Can we use PHP classes in Asp.net

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, web-services

I have got some library files in PHP. i want to use them in asp.net. please give me some idea that how to use it or how to convert it to be used in asp.net (vb.net). actually i want to connect with a xml based web service (HostelsClub) but they just have API in PHP not in asp.net. so what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way how it works with c#

[Tomasp.net](http://tomasp.net/blog/ducktyping-in-phalaner.aspx)

I'm not sure about vb.net but it's .net at all.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an XML service, especially if it is a 3rd party service, and is performing fine in PHP, why not simply call the service from .net using XML-RPC or similar?  I'm not sure from your question that you actually need to be re-writing the PHP service.

XML services should be consumable from any language providing the XML call structures are known.

Although their API is written in PHP that should be irrelevant *unless* it is a code-dependent API.  Reading between the lines of your query ("want to connect to...") it's not clear whether this is a local library that you *need* to connect to from PHP to PHP, or whether you simply need to call/connect to a web based service that has been built on-top of the library that you mention.  If it's a web-based service then all major protocols are certainly possible in .net, php, ruby, perl, etc.

Comment: yes its a webservice. can u please tell me how to work with XML-RPC.

Answer (score 1):

Hai,

Have a look at this

http://sanity-free.org/125/php_webservices_and_csharp_dotnet_soap_clients.html

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to learn more than one language so you aren't completely dependent on any particular vendor.